# Rails engine / How to use seed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, seed

I have created a Rails Engine. I am having trouble using the seed command, if I run rake db:seed I get the error: "uninitialized constant".

In the engine, I got a seeds.rb:

`Page.create(:title => 'Frontpage', :order => '1')`

Then in my dummy app I got a seeds.rb with

```
cms::Engine.load_seed
```

(cms being the name of the engine) -- I got an error now though, that "uninitialized constant ". How do I reference the constant from the dummy app?

Comment: What version of ruby\rails do you use?

Comment: Also, try this command: "rake cms:db:seed". Where cms - name of engine. And look at "rake -T" - this will be return to you full list of available commands.

Comment: Thanks - I tried the command, I still get "uninitialized constant Page". I generated the model "page".

Comment: Rails 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, got it! - the answer is:

In the engine, add a seeds.rb in the db folder, prepend the app name to each constant, like so:

```
Cms::Page.create(:title => 'Frontpage', :order => '1')
```

In the dummy app, or the app where you are adding your engine, add a seeds.rb to the db folder with:

```
Cms::Engine.load_seed
```

and run:

```
rake db:seed
```

in the terminal.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this process automatically rather than adding the load_seed method manually. I wondering about the use case where a gem can be added and removed.